# A basic question on limit point metric space etc

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose we have a metric space $X$ and we have an order on $X$. Now, let $E$ be a subset of $X$ which is bounded above. Now let $E'$ be the set of all limit points of $E$. If $E' \neq \emptyset$ then is it true that $E'$ has the greatest element (i.e. there is one element in $E'$ which is greater than equal to all elements in $E'$)? I think so. How to prove it ?

Comment: Even if $E$ is bounded above, it might not have a greatest element. Think of $(0,1)$.

Comment: And if it has a greatest element, say $g$, then think of two cases- $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $[0,1]$. In the first case, $5$ is not a limit point of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, while in the second case, $1$ is a limit point of $[0,1]$.

Comment: What you can show is that E' contains the least upper bound.

Comment: @AyushKhaitan: if $E=(0,1)$ then $1 \in E'$ and there is no other element in $E'$ which is higher than $1$. Also, I said $E' \neq \phi$.

Comment: @Prasenjit- Even then, $1$ is not the greatest element of $(0,1)$. It is the supremum.

Comment: @Betty: Not so, if you mean "the least upper bound of $E$." Consider $E=[0,1]\cup\{2\}$. See my answer for more detail on alternative situations.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: I see now that you want to show that for an orderable set $X$ with a metric, and a subset $E$ of $X$ bounded above and such that $E'$ is non-empty, we have a greatest element of $E'.$ This is indeed not the case, *even if* we make the order topologically compatible with the metric (that is, the topology induced by the order and that induced by the metric are identical).

Take $X=\Bbb Q$ with the usual order and the absolute difference metric, $E=\{x\in X:x^2<2\}$. Then $E$ is bounded above, and $E'=E\ne\emptyset,$ but $E'$ has no greatest element.

If you want $X=\Bbb R$ with the usual order *and* metric, then you are correct. Indeed, noting that $E'$ is a closed set (why?) we find that if $E'$ has no greatest element, then it is not bounded above, so neither is $E$ bounded above, a contradiction.

If you allow the order or metric to be *arbitrary*, then this need not hold. Let $<$ indicate the usual order on $\Bbb R,$ and $d$ the usual (absolute difference) metric. Consider the functions $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ given by $$f(x)=\begin{cases}-x & x\in\Bbb Q\\x & \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$ We define an order relation $\prec$ on $\Bbb R$ by $x\prec y\iff f(x)<f(y)$ and we define a metric $m$ on $\Bbb R$ by $m(x,y)=d\bigl(f(x),f(y)\bigr).$ Considering $\Bbb R$ under the order $\prec$ and the usual metric, we see that $E=\{x\in\Bbb Q:x>0\}\cup\{x\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q:x<0\}=\{x\in\Bbb R:x\prec 0\}$ is bounded above, but $E'=\Bbb R$ has no greatest element. On the other hand, considering $\Bbb R$ under the metric $m$ and the usual order, we see that $E=\{x\in\Bbb R:x<0\}$ is bounded above, but $E'=\Bbb R$ has no greatest element.

Comment: I think there is some confusion. What I meant is that I want to show that it not true that for every element in $E'$ we can find a higher element in $E'$ because $E'$ is the set of all "limit" points of $E$. I just want a formal argument for that.

Comment: Ah! I see your correction, now. You want to show that $E'$ has a greatest element, yes? Before I can answer that, I have a question: are the order on $X$ and the metric on $X$ compatible in some way, or is $X$ just an orderable set with a metric? The answer may differ depending on which you mean.

Comment: $X$ is just an orderable set with a metric. I just want to make the term "greatest" making sense.

Comment: Answer updated. The answer is (again) "no."

Comment: If $X=\Bbb R$ then is my conjecture correct ? yes, i corrected that least upper bound part.

Comment: Answer updated again. The answer is a conditional "yes," this time.